# how to upload files in viewflow

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-viewflow, viewflow

I'm trying to upload a document attached to the flow in viewflow as another field as would a string or an int, but when I put in the model

Answer = FilerFileField ()

I do not recognize it view flow in the fields

Fields = ["Answer"]

Answer (score 0):

To upload files you need to use `<form enctype=multipart/form-data>` in the template

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/file-uploads/

Comment: I did `file = models.FileField()` in my `models.py` and it uploads the file BUT how can I preview it on review?